# How can I inverse a transposed convolutional layer?

Tags: convolution

I am interested in inversing a transposed convolution operation (or "deconvolution", and not straightforward convolution).

A transposed convolution usually maps data points from a smaller feature space (latent space) onto a much larger feature space (image space), so the inverse should not be ambiguous, or should it?

[image]

Is there an established mathematical framework for performing the inversion? If not, how do you suggest approach the problem?